# Difficulty with events

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm having trouble understanding the events. Whenever I see an example of a code with events, I can not find the documentation of them, just being able to understand testing. In this code, for example, I understood the 'SIGINT' by testing, but I did not find the documentation. The 'end' I could not find the documentation and also I can not understand when the 'end' will be fired. What happens to these events? Why so much trouble finding the documentation? Are events contextual? How to know the context and where to search? Thank you and sorry for the stupid question.

```
const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => { inputString
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    inputString = inputString.replace(/\s*$/, '')
        .split('\n')
        .map(str => str.replace(/\s*$/, ''));

    main();
});
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

Comment: [process.stdin](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) is an instance of [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream) object. You can read the documentation on it.

Comment: "The 'end' event is emitted when there is no more data to be consumed from the stream." What does mean this? When I will not have more data to be consumed??????

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation of streams: https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/streams.html

You can see that stdin is a Stream: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin

So, whatever applies to Stream, applies to stdin as well.

data event:

> The 'data' event emits either a Buffer (by default) or a string if
>   setEncoding() was used.

So, data event is loading a chunk of data from the Stream into either a Buffer or a string.

end event:

> Emitted when the stream has received an EOF (FIN in TCP terminology).
>   Indicates that no more 'data' events will happen. If the stream is
>   also writable, it may be possible to continue writing.

So, the end event is triggered, unsurprisingly, when the last data event happened.

To explain this, let's suppose you have a Stream of a file of the size of 2 GB. In this case, chunks of data are loaded from that file, let's suppose that the size of the chunks is S. In this case, you will have around 2 GB / S steps of loading. This means that there will be many data events and the system will always trigger a data event while there is a next packet to load. At the end, when there is nothing more to load, it will trigger the end event. Now that we understand Streams, I think you now understand that the same thing happens for stdin as well. Nothing prevents the possibility that stdin would suddenly receive a very large amount of data.

Comment: Thanks Brother! I understood your explanation perfectly and this documantation is wonderfull. However, I still have doubts. When I call my stream (process.stdin), does it have size set by default? Why is the 'date' event only triggered when I hit enter button on console? How exactly do you work with Streams? Can you send me an example code where a stream is consumed without a hit enter button and the 'end' event working finelly? Thans

Comment: Or, how to make this simple example by from the documentation works? How to emit 'end' event??????????????? https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/process.html#process.stdin

Comment: @Marcosautomação when you type something into the console, the content is not ready yet for stdin, because you need to have a chance of correcting typos before your input is finalized. Try pasting a large text into the console and benchmarking it. The end event runs when there is no more data to read on the stream. I think it's not a good idea to emit an end event. As about the size of the data, that's a very good question. I do not know how is it defined. It must have a default value, but I'm now sure how you can alter it.